# PowerPivot for SharePoint 2013 - GallerySnapshot.exe 0KB

Tags: powerpivot, powerview

For some reason, the GallerySnapshot.exe located in the 15 hive of SharePoint 2013 was modified and became 0 KB. Where can I get this file? Can someone provide this file? Thanks!

Comment: This is a Windows service that runs on the app server where Excel Services is installed. How many server you have int he farm, easy way to configure the ECS on other server and you will see this file over there.

Comment: Hi Waqas, thanks for answering my question. We finally got the file after installing spPowerPivot.msi or PowerPivot for SharePoint 2013. After that you have to run the configuration tool for it to produce the .exe file to the 15 hive.

Answer (score -1):

The file can be obtained by installing PowerPivot for SharePoint 2013 and then running the configuration tool.